# Google Maps Not Appearing

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to add a basic google Map to my site but nothing is showing, I checked the console and there are no errors, simply put nothing happens

JS Script

```
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="Javascript/googleMaps.js"></script>

    <script async defersrc="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APKKEYHERE&callback=initMap"></script>
<title>cONTACT</title>
</head>

<body>

        <div id="map" class="googleMaps"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Was wondering if anyone can see what I am doing wrong ?? Fyi I removed the API key it is there in the live code

Comment: @LukeStoward Tried that didnt work

Comment: If your problem was the result of a typo, such as missing a space between `defer` and `src`, please delete your question because it will not be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it Out

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="Javascript/googleMaps.js"></script>

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APKKEYHERE&callback=initMap"></script>
<title>cONTACT</title>
</head>
```

Comment: please explain in some detail how you figured it out for the rest of the community,

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a `width` and `height` for your content like

`<div id="map" class="googleMaps" style="min-height: 400px; min-width: 400px"></div>`

Comment: Thats already done in the style sheet, so this is not an answer

Comment: Maybe you can provide an online example with codepen.io ?